# Why are the numbers not getting swapped even after using pointers in C?

Tags: c

Even after using pointers the numbers are not getting swapped in the main function. I know there is some reason but could not find what it is?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int*, int*);

int main()
{
    int *ptr, *ptr2;

    int num1 = 90;
    int num2 = 900;

    ptr = &num1;
    ptr2 = &num2;

    printf("Before swapping the values : %d : %d \n", *ptr, *ptr2);
    swap(&num1,&num2);
    printf("After calling the swap function : %d : %d \n", *ptr, *ptr2);

    return 0;
}

void swap(int *ptr, int *ptr2)
{
    int *temp;

    temp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr2;
    ptr2 = temp;

    printf("In the swap function : %d : %d\n", *ptr, *ptr2); 
}
```

the output is still 90 900

Comment: Because you're operating on the pointers, not the pointees.

Comment: dereference the pointers, e.g. `temp=*ptr` etc.

Comment: Pass the pointers by reference :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are swapping the pointers, not the pointed values. Change the swap function into:

```
void swap(int *ptr, int *ptr2)
{
    int temp = *ptr;
    *ptr = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping the local copies of the pointers, and not the data it self. You should do something like this:

```
void swap(int * ptr,int *ptr2)
{
int temp;

temp=*ptr;
*ptr=*ptr2;
*ptr2=temp;
}
```

And you don't need ptr and ptr2 in main().

Answer (score 0):

What you probably intend to do is swap the values and not the pointers (which are not not even swapped in main, due to "copy by value")
You probably intend:

```
void swap(int *ptr, int *ptr2)
{
    int temp = *ptr;
    *ptr= *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
}
```